# Mock Django QuerySet on managed=False model - unit test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, orm, mocking

I'm testing a **Django** application with unit test, and I need to mock a QuerySet like this one.

```
def function_to_be_tested():
    qs = myModel.objects.get_last(param_1, param_2)
                                            .filter(category__in=[category_1, category_2])
    return qs
```

**myModel**

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

    objects = myModelManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        ...
```

**myModelManager**

```
class myModelManager(models.manager):

    def get_last(self, param_1, param_2):
        # Do some stuff
```

Following my attempt, which uses *mock*

```
with mock.patch('path.of.module.myModel.objects.get_last') as my_model_data:
    my_model_data.return_value = myModel.objects.none()
    result = module.function_to_be_tested()
```

This case works fine, because returns an empty list. Now, i would like mock the QuerySet in order to return some data.

```
with mock.patch('path.of.module.myModel.objects.get_last') as my_model_data:
    mock_data = mock.MagicMock(spec=myModel)
    mock_data.category = 'category_x'
    my_model_data.return_value = [mock_data]
    result = module.function_to_be_tested()
```

This attempt fails with the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

I understand that this happens because i'm mocking only the *get_last* function and not all QuerySet.

I tried to add also `filter` to the path like this:

```
with mock.patch('path.of.module.myModel.objects.get_last.filter') as my_model_data:
```

but raises

```
AttributeError: <bound method myModelManager.get_last of 
<path of.myModelManager object at 0x04EF49F0>> does not have the attribute 'filter'
```

Is it possible mock this kind of QuesrySet? if yes, what am I missing?

Comment: If you really need to return/test with actual model instances then why not create some instances of the model and then test the function directly without mocking?

Comment: Take a look if this SO post helps you find an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362952/mocking-a-django-queryset-in-order-to-test-a-function-that-takes-a-queryset

Comment: @AKS, thanks for the comment, btw, i think that i can't do this because myModel is managed=False. I've edited the question, sorry for the missing information