# Django unit test mock queryset from related object

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-queryset, django-testing

I have the following function:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock


def get_payments(order):
    return order.payments.filter(status='complete').order_by('-date_added)
```

I want to mock the `filter` method and the `order_by` to check the arguments with which are called.

I tried:

```
class TestPayments(unittest.TestCase):
     @mock.patch('path.Order.payments.filter.order_by')
     @mock.patch('path.Order.payments.filter')
     def test_get_payments(self, mock1, mock2):
        mock1.assert_called_with(status='complete')
        mock2.assert_called_with('-date_added')
```

Another mock I tried:

```
@mock.patch('path.Payment.objects.filter.order_by')
@mock.patch('path.Payment.objects.filter')

@mock.patch('path.Order.payments.objects.filter.order_by')
@mock.patch('path.Order.payments.objects.filter')
```

In last two mocks I have an error that `path.Order` does not exists.
I already used a direct mock for a query like `Payment.objects.filter()` and is working, but starting from a related model like `Order` I failed.

The relationship between `Order` and `Payment` is how you would expect, one to many.

Comment: you can use django `TestCase` instead of python's unittest. `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/`

Comment: I'm using TestCase. Also your link is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by mocking objects I resolved this.

```
    order = MagicMock(side_effect=Order())
    order.payments.filter.return_value = MagicMock(side_effect=Payment.objects.filter(id=0))
    order.payments.filter.return_value.order_by.return_value = [Payment()]

    order.payments.filter.assert_called_with(status='complete')
    order.payments.filter.return_value.order_by.assert_called_with('-date_updated')
```

Answer (score 3):

To explain what happens here: QuerySet methods like `filter()`, `exclude()`, `order_by()` etc. return a QuerySet, that is why they can be chained.

What you tried first is trying to patch the methods as if they would be in a package hierarchy. What you ended up doing is not patching the method but mocking the return value for each chained method, which is how it is done.

Unfortunately there is not much documentation on this. When I ran into this problem I had some stackoverflow answers that helped me, but I can't seem to find them again.

Similar questions (where the answers don't really provide an explaination):

- [Django ORM - mock values().filter() chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883906/django-orm-mock-values-filter-chain)
- [Mocking a Django Queryset in order to test a function that takes a queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362952/mocking-a-django-queryset-in-order-to-test-a-function-that-takes-a-queryset)

There are libraries out there that might help you: [mock-django](https://github.com/dcramer/mock-django) provides an ORM mocking class. Their approach to [mocking QuerySet methods](https://github.com/dcramer/mock-django/blob/master/mock_django/query.py) is quite interesting. What I personally found very useful for testing Django models is [Model Mommy](http://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), because it helps you to create easy mocks of models.